# typedef function return value in C

Tags: c, typedef

Please help me understand what this typedef is doing??

```
typedef void (xyz) (void *data);
extern struct x* FUNCTION(xyz *ptr);
```

Here is my understanding: in 1st line xyz is a function returning void and taking void pointer as an argument.  But I cant interpret 2nd line with this understanding.

Any input is appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an external function called `FUNCTION` which takes a pointer to an `xyz` function as parameter and returns a pointer to a `struct x`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line defines `xyz` to be the type of a function returning `void` and taking one argument of type `void*`. You can actually omit the name `data`, as it does nothing.

Since there are no raw function types in C that you can declare directly, you can only use *pointers* to `xyz`, as indeed you have `xyz * ptr`.

It is more common to include the pointer in the typedef:

```
typedef void (*fptr)(void*);

void call(fptr f, void * arg) { f(arg); }

void some_function(void * data); // whatever

int main()
{
    void * p = malloc(8);
    call(some_function, p);
}
```

---

The second line declares a function that takes an `xyz*` as an argument and returns a pointer to a `struct x`, with external linkage.

Comment: This does not answer the question, since it was about the second line of the code.

Comment: @Archie: OK, I added an explanation of the second line.